# Delete several Image dependencies

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to link several docker images. How do I reduce the number of dependent images that are created after docker-compose build? Whenever I install a package I have to build, they pile up below the tagged image several untagged images that occupy so much space.

Comment: Can you give an actual example of your configuration, the command you're running, and the output you're seeing?  The only case where there could be extra images lying around is from the early parts of a multi-stage build.  (If you're running `docker images -a`, don't.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with multistage builds:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

*The end result is the same tiny production image as before, with a significant reduction in complexity. You don’t need to create any intermediate images and you don’t need to extract any artifacts to your local system at all.*